# Gradle sync failed: No such property: logger for class: org.gradle.initialization.DefaultProjectDescriptor

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I have created an App on react native. It was successfully running on my MacBook Air. Now I got a new MacBook with an M1 chip. I am trying to set up my on that new system. Following are the versions of my system:

```
react = 17.0.1 
react-native = 0.63.4 
Node = v16.10.0 
Java = openjdk version "1.8.0_292" 
Android Studio Artic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3
Gradle = 6.1
```

Can Someone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: did you ever find out what was wrong? I have the same issue!

Comment: I have updated the android Gradle to latest and everything is working now